# How to Add Specific Column When inserting Value on Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I am trying to insert a value and calculating the value that i inserted into one column.

the example, basically I have one table with 3 column on it, `id`, `amount`, `total`:

```
id | amount | total
1 | 100 | 100 
2 | 200 | 300
3 | -100 | 200
```

expected result:

every time a new `amount` value is entered, I want the value in column `total` to be added with that value

```
INSERT INTO public.tb_total_amount
(id, amount, total, create_time)
VALUES(1, 100, balance+amount, NOW());
```

is it ok to accumulate the negative value? and,
anyone can correct my query? thank you

Answer (score 1):

I recommend against doing this, and I instead suggest just using `SUM` as an analytic function:

```
SELECT
    id,
    amount,
    SUM(amount) OVER (ORDER BY id) total
FROM yourTable;
```

The logic behind this answer is that your rolling sum `total` is derived, and not original, data.  Therefore, it is better to just compute it on the fly when you need it, rather than storing it.

If you really want to insert the correct total during a single insert, you may try:

```
INSERT INTO public.tb_total_amount (amount, total, create_time)
SELECT
    100,
    (SELECT COALESCE(amount, 0) FROM public.tb_total_amount
     ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) + 100,
    NOW();
```

Comment: can you explain why against?

Comment: The rolling sum is derived data, and in general it should probably not be stored in your table.

Comment: what if i still want to store the value into table? do you have a solution for it?

Comment: @CodeOn I gave you an option using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`.

Comment: the insert query with select will got error when there's no row before

Comment: No, there won't be an error, but you may use `COALESCE` to handle this initial edge case.